# Entity Framework 6 - How to Model this Relationship with Fluent API

Tags: entity-framework, orm, entity-framework-6, npgsql, ef-fluent-api

**TLDR** - Can I make a separate table using Entity Framework that only identifies a one to many relationship? The many side has no knowledge of the one side.

I have a Polygon class, appearing here in simple form:

```
public class Polygon
{
    List<LineSegment> _lineSegments = new List<LineSegment>();
    public List<LineSegment> LineSegments
    {
        get { return _lineSegments; }
        protected set { _lineSegments = value; }
    }

    // ...
}
```

And the `LineSegment` class, which has no natural reference to a Polygon, nor do I want to add one solely for EF's sake:

```
public class LineSegment
{
    public virtual Distance Magnitude
    {
        get { return _magnitude; }
        set { _magnitude = value; }
    }
    private Distance _magnitude;

     public virtual Point BasePoint
    {
        get { return _basePoint; }
        set { this._basePoint = value; }
    }
    private Point _basePoint;

     public virtual Direction Direction
    {
        get { return _direction; }
        set { _direction = value; }
    }
    private Direction _direction;

    // ...
}
```

So there is a one to many relationship here. This should be handled, according to the principles of normalization, with a separate table that associates Polygon IDs with LineSegment IDs. However, when I map the following with Fluent API,

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Polygon>()
        .HasMany(polygon => polygon.LineSegments);
```

EF expects a Polygon_DatabaseId in the LineSegments table. It wouldn't be the first time that EF broke normalization. But I can set this up as a many to many relationship, which will create the third table:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Polygon>()
        .HasMany(polygon => polygon.LineSegments)
        .WithMany();
```

I can insert things into this table just fine. However, when I attempt to get them out and back into a Polygon object, LineSegments are not loaded. Here is the querying code:

```
private static List<Expression<Func<Polygon, object>>> polygonRegionNaviationProperties = new List<Expression<Func<Polygon, object>>>()
{
    (polygon => polygon.LineSegments.Select(lineSegment => lineSegment.Magnitude)),
    (polygon => polygon.LineSegments.Select(lineSegment => lineSegment.BasePoint.X)),
    (polygon => polygon.LineSegments.Select(lineSegment => lineSegment.BasePoint.Y)),
    (polygon => polygon.LineSegments.Select(lineSegment => lineSegment.BasePoint.Z))
};

public Polygon GetPolygon(int? databaseId)
{
    if(databaseId != null)
    {
        Polygon retrievedPolygon = Query((polygon => polygon.DatabaseId == databaseId), polygonRegionNaviationProperties);
        return retrievedPolygon;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

And the generic querying method:

```
public virtual T Query(Expression<Func<T, bool>> match, List<Expression<Func<T, object>>> includes = null)
{
    using (var databaseContext = new ClearspanDatabaseContext())
    {
        databaseContext.Database.Log = Console.Write;
        if (includes != null)
        {
            var dataSet = databaseContext.Set<T>(); // Get the relevant DataSet
            T retrievedObject = includes.Aggregate( // Eagerly load the passed navigation properties
                    dataSet.AsQueryable(),
                    (current, include) => current.Include(include)
                ).SingleOrDefault(match);
            return retrievedObject;
        }
        else
        {
            T retrievedObject = databaseContext.Set<T>().SingleOrDefault(match);
            return retrievedObject;
        }
    }
}
```

**So is it possible to model this relationship such that we make a one to many table separate from the Polygons and LineSegments tables? If so, how do I do this with Fluent API? Thanks in advance.**

Comment: In the database, does the LineSegments table have a foreign key back to the Polygons table? In a one-to-many table relationship, this would be the normal thing. If you have an table between Polygons and LineSegments with columns (PolygonId, LineSegmentId) then you would have a many-to-many relationship.

Comment: Currently no, there is no foreign key back to the Polygons table. The separate table does facilitate a many-to-many relationship, but it allows for one-to-many as well. If I add the column to the LineSegments table, I'm imagining that there are other things (Polyhedrons might be an example) that have collections of LineSegments as well, so it seems like the LineSegments table could get polluted with many nullable foreign key columns, which doesn't seem right. What do you think?